# How to Iterate the tokenized pytorch Multi30k dataset in BucketIterator?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, spacy-transformers

I am using Pytorch(1.10 v), I am using Multi30k German to English dataset for machine translation. I am using spacy for tokenization (both for English and German words) and wanna pass the tokenized data to (**torchtext.legacy.data.BucketIterator**) for padding and for converting string to index. Some error is occurring related to sort_key, I am not getting it. Somebody, please help me out.

The code

```
import spacy
from torchtext.datasets import Multi30k # this is a en and gr dataset for machine translation
from torchtext.legacy.data import Field, BucketIterator

spacy_eng = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
spacy_ger = spacy.load("de_core_news_sm")

def tokenize_eng(text):
    return [tok.text for tok in spacy_eng.tokenizer(text)]

def tokenize_ger(text):
    return [tok.text for tok in spacy_ger.tokenizer(text)]

english = Field(sequential=True, use_vocab=True, tokenize=tokenize_eng, lower=True, init_token='<sos>', eos_token='<eos>')
german = Field(sequential=True, use_vocab=True, tokenize=tokenize_ger, lower=True, init_token='<sos>', eos_token='<eos>')

train, valid, test = Multi30k(root=".data", split=('train', 'valid', 'test'), language_pair=('en', 'de'))

# will make vocabulary from train data
english.build_vocab(train, max_size=10000, min_freq=2)
german.build_vocab(train, max_size=10000, min_freq=2)


train_data, valid_data, test_data = BucketIterator.splits((train, valid, test),
                                                          batch_size=64,
                                                          device='cuda')
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Torch\Multi30K_inbuilt_dataset.py", line 28, in <module>
    train_data, valid_data, test_data = BucketIterator.splits((train, valid, test),
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\torchtext\legacy\data\iterator.py", line 99, in splits
    ret.append(cls(
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\torchtext\legacy\data\iterator.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.sort_key = dataset.sort_key
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataset.py", line 226, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope its not too late, but try to use :

```
train, valid, test = Multi30k.splits(exts=('.de', '.en'), fields=(german, english))
```

Comment: This function won't going to work in PyTorch new version.